# Can one MVC Edit Template delegate to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, razor-2

I have a strongly-typed Razor 2 editor template. When the view model meets certain conditions, I want the view to delegate to an alternative template of the same type. I use the TemplateName argument to the EditorFor helper to select the alternative template:

```
@model MyType
@if (Model.IsSpecialCase)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m, "SpecialCaseTemplate")
}
else
{
    @* Default markup *@
}
```

Problem is, Razor does not call the alternative template; it simply passes over the EditorFor method. If I change the type of the second template, it shows it correctly. I can work around this using a Partial View, but I would rather not, as I have a scheme going with Editor Templates that I want to stick to.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

**Edit**

Looks like this has something to do with the behaviour described here: [ASP.net MVC - Using EditorFor with the same model type twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402325/asp-net-mvc-using-editorfor-with-the-same-model-type-twice?rq=1). In short, that MVC does not support using the EditorFor method on the same object twice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, is by returning a different view from your Controller:

```
public ActionResult someaction(){
    var Model = ...;
    if (Model.IsSpecialCase){
        return View("SpecialCaseTemplate");
    }
    else{
        return View();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do in the view like this:

```
@model MyType
@if (Model.IsSpecialCase)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("SpecialCaseTemplate", model);
}
else
{
    @* Default markup *@
}
```

Comment: @Kennneth, thanks, but neither of those approaches are really convenient in the scenario that I'm using. I summarised the problem to make it easy to read, but in fact, the types in question are embedded in a complex, hierarchical model. The partial view approach works, but isn't consistent with my use of editor templates for the rest of the  model.